# How to use smbclient to connect anonymously to a server?

Tags: 16.04, samba, smb

System: Ubuntu 16.04

Smbclient: Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu

I can use `Connect to server` in the folder and choose `Anonymous` to connect to my server correctly, but when I try `smbclient //serverip/folder`, it returns:

```
Domain=[WORKGROUP] 
OS=[Windows 6.1] 
Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

Why?

And, where does the system amount the server, when I use GUI to connect to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] The easiest way for me to reproduce your error is to try to access a subfolder of the share - as in `smbclient //server/share/subfolder` OR  `smbclient //server/subfolder`.

The sytnax is: `smbclient //server/share`

[2] When you use Connect to Server it mounts under `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`